# PWA 'Add To Screen' Prompt doesn't work after downloading a file

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

During my work on launching add to screen prompt on my website, I have created a service worker file and also added an event listener for 'beforeinstallprompt'.
Then I just stored the event, for using the prompt later, and that's works fine.

The problem starts when user is downloading a file on my website, and then I'm trying to launch the prompt, it just doesn't work.

The variable (the stored event of 'beforeinstallprompt') is exists, but the .prompt() function is not running as should be.

I disproved it is a time issue (I tried to launch the prompt after 5 minutes, it has been launched well), and I just don't have other idea why can it happen.

Comment: This prompt is created by you manually or the automatic chrome mini-info bar?

Comment: @Mathias I'm firing it manually. It's working great, until I'm trying to fire it after user downloaded a file.